# Accessing hardware infos on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to write an app that displays hardware infos such as the number of kernels in the processor, the available RAM, GPS, motion sensors?

Using `CoreLocation` and `CoreMotion` it's not possible to know for sure if a GPS or an accelerometer is present on the device because of the Location Services switch.

Is it possible to check deeper for hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much no.  You can get some general, implied information, for example by allocating RAM until you get a warning, and then assuming that's your available RAM.  You can also check for availability of certain services, for example by asking CLLocationManager if locationServicesEnabled.  But you can't get detailed information about it to know for sure if, for example, the GPS is there, but it's just turned off.

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Check the iPhone Developers Coockbook (  Erica Sadun, http://ericasadun.com ) for the UIDevice Class - UIDevice-Hardware (direct link here: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.h ) - but I'd also recommend getting the Book. Pretty good stuff, and the UIDevice Extensions are pretty good.
**Please note that some of that stuff is private API! - you won't be able to submit it!**